# What is the preferred way to add custom data to a Wordpress theme?

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

I've read a number of articles and tutorials on adding custom content to a Wordpress theme. They almost always refer to small bits of data such as telephone numbers or emails that can be easily handled by using the option mechanism in Wordpress. This is fine and I've managed to implement the same functionality in a number of ways.

My question is;

If I wanted to add an option for the author to have some custom content on the home page - say a banner image, a paragraph of text (that uses the HTML editor) and a link to another page, what would be the most Wordpress friendly way of doing this?

I should probably mention that I'm not looking for a how-to or step by step, just opinions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is using the [settings api](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API). A good tutorial for this is on [wp.tutsplus](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-the-settings-api-part-1-create-a-theme-options-page/), Its quite long. A shorter is from [Otto](http://ottopress.com/2009/wordpress-settings-api-tutorial/).
It can be quite confusing at the beginning, but it's not that hard.

Comment: Thanks janw. I have implemented custom functionality in this way in the past, and it always works well. I'm not sure whether to do this through writing a plugin or by using functions.php with includes?

Comment: If these settings are theme settings put them in your theme ;) To keep it organised I advise to make a folder with includes